# Crash on start on iOS 12

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios12

Since compiling our app for iOS 17, Devices running iOS 12 crash on start.  The debugger doesn't even call `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` before the crash.

Seems to point to `ImageLoaderMachO::` error

Did I miss a memo on something new we have to do now when supporting images for `iOS` 12 and below?

Comment: https://github.com/realm/realm-swift/issues/8369 ?

Comment: Nailed it! thank you so much for that link.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Larme's comment and link.

The issue appears to be with linking.  Adding `-Wl,-ld_classic` in `OTHER_LDFLAGS` in the target Build Settings is the fix.